# How to parameterize the SQL query in karate

Tags: karate

- def query = read(intitation.sql);
- string output = query

I want to parameterize and the pass the **column2 ='value'** dynamically from feature file, can you help me in how to achieve this.

Below is the sql file intitation.sql:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10, column11, column12 FROM table1 WHERE **column2='value'**;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal JS fundamentals:

```
* def value = 'foo'    
* def sql = "select * from dogs where name = '" + value + "'"
```

Also see `replace` if it helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace

EDIT: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71063078/143475

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would also work?   Just something to chew on as being an interesting solution.   On more complicated parameterizations, this could work well.

```
* def String = Java.type('java.lang.String')
* def pString = "Select * from Whatever where id = '%s' and name = '%s'"
* def query = String.format(pString, "my-id", "my-name")
```

Also, could perhaps load the Java `PreparedStatement` class?

Comment: for those coming across this, please note that karate supports ES6 string interpolation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71063078/143475