# Karate Java String interpolation

Tags: java, karate

I am trying to call a java method that accepts a string as a parameter inside a karate script, and interpolate a value defined in karate in that string.

In my case it's a simple database INSERT statement, for example:

```
INSERT INTO A(id, time, value) VALUES(1, '2099-05-10 18:20:18.674 UTC', 'test')
```

The script itself looks as follows:

```
Background:
    * def db = Java.type('com.example.DbTestHelper')
    * def offsetDateTime = Java.type('java.time.OffsetDateTime')
    * def zoneId = Java.type('java.time.ZoneId')

  Scenario: testScenario
    * def t = offsetDateTime.now(zoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).plusDays(1)
    * def row = db.insertRow("INSERT INTO A(id, time, value) VALUES(123, #t, 'test')")
```

And the *insertRow* method looks as follows:

```
    @JvmStatic
    fun insertRow(vararg strings: String) {
        jdbc.batchUpdate(*strings)
    }
```

I have tried multiple combinations of setting value *t* like #(t), #t, "#(t)" etc. Unfortunately, none of them worked resulting in various javascript parse errors even before the java method gets invoked.

What would be the right way to achieve that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions

The good news is that in 1.0 onwards Karate supports ES6 JS string interpolation within backticks:

```
* def foo = 1
* def txt = `hello ${foo}`
* match txt == 'hello 1'
```

Of course string concatenation will always work. You just have to think of most Karate syntax especially when you call Java - as being nothing but plain old JavaScript.

```
* db.insertRow("INSERT INTO A(id, time, value) VALUES(123, " + t + ", 'test')")
```

I think you will be able to proceed now.