# Karate: db validation failing with extraneous input error

Tags: database, karate

I am relatively new to karate. The current flow requires me to validate the api response and also validate the db for the saved response. For db validation I am trying to use the below:

- def suppMat = db.readValue(“select column1, column2, column3 from table1 where relId = 12345”)
  And match the result with below:

And match suppMat == { column1: < column1 >, column2: < column2 >, column3: < column3 > }
Examples:
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
|abcp1234 | 6       | 5       |

But this is giving me an error:
Extraneous input ‘\r\n Examples:’ expecting {, scenario, scenario_outline, tags, newline}

Probably this is not the right approach. But could someone please help with the solution?

- def suppMat = db.readValue(“select column1, column2, column3 from table1 where relId = 12345”)
  And match the result with below:

And match suppMat == { column1: , column2: , column3:  }
Examples:
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
|abcp1234 | 6       | 5       |

But this is giving me an error:
Extraneous input ‘\r\n Examples:’ expecting {, scenario, scenario_outline, tags, newline}

Probably this is not the right approach. But could someone please help with the solution?

Comment: this will be a simple matter of putting the quotes and not using the `<>` of placeholders. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62707892/143475